# .htaccess rewrite rule for email / token

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't make this work, any ideas?

.htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/([^/]*)/(.*)/&$ unsubscribe.php?hash=$1&email=$2
```

I'm trying to transform this URL:

```
unsubscribe.php?hash=dbacb2d010eb022619e90c8df2654aab273&email=enriquealbiola@iqs.edu
```

To this one:

```
unsubscribe/dbacb2d010eb022619e90c8df2654aab273/enriquealbiola@iqs.edu
```

I've really tried searching, and the code I have is what I got, but it isn't working...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/([^/]*)/(.*)/&$ unsubscribe.php?hash=$1&email=$2
```

By this one :

```
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ /unsubscribe.php?hash=$1&email=$2 [L]
```