# Simple .htaccess rewrite rule returning 'Not Found' issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^referral/([0-9]+)/?$ /referral.php?code=$1 [NC,L]
```

It is supposed to do two things:

- block the access to folders' content
- modifies a URL that ends with `referral/test@email.com` to `referral.php?code=test@email.com`.

Different formats have been tried, but the same error comes up:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /referral/test@email.com was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 443

The first line of code works fine alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing other related questions (notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144297/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-email-token)), I finally got it to work by adding the following line:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^referral/([0-9]+)/?$ /referral.php?code=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^referral/([0-9]+)/?$`) does not match a URL of the form "an address that ends with `referral/test@email.com`". For that you would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^referral/([a-zA-Z0-9.@-]+)$ /referral.php?code=$1 [L]
```

This assumes that the URL "ends with" an email address, but that is otherwise the complete URL. The regex `[0-9]+` only matches digits, not an email address (letters, digits, "@", ".", etc.), that you appear to require.

I've also removed the `NC` flag and incorporated the case-insensitivity into the regex, since I assume only the email address could be mixed case, not the URL-path?

Comment: Still same error. Your code makes a lot more sense. You are right about the entire URL.

Comment: Does a request for `example.com/referral.php?code=test@email.com` work? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` files?

Comment: example.com/referral.php?code=test@email.com works fine, htaccess contains just Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule referral/([a-zA-Z0-9.@-]+)$ /referral.php?code=$1 [L]

Comment: Try (temporarily) changing this to an external redirect. ie. Change the `RewriteRule` flags from `[L]` to `[R,L]` - does it redirect? (This is just to help with debugging.)